# Outlets still have power but fuse is unscrewed?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an old house with a fuse box on the second floor of the home, and 200A service with breaker box in the basement. The fuse box is fed by a 30A line. The fuse box has 24 fuses and seems to integrate with much of the house.

Today I traced my living room electric with a circuit breaker finder to the fuse box. I unscrewed the fuse and the expected outlets lost power. However, when I passed these outlets and their plugged in items with a noncontact voltage tester, I got the same positive readings one does when the fuse is plugged in. Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: this is not the jog and an non-contact tester.  You are out of the scope of a non-contact tester.  You need something more reliable.

Comment: I don't understand. What is more reliable?

Comment: When you have the "fuse" removed but the non-contact tester shows a response, will the receptacle power a lamp?

Comment: @JimStewart no, it will not power a lamp but the cord shows voltage through the noncontact.

Comment: Can you get a multimeter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can tomorrow. What should I look for with it? Should I test the plugged in cord?

Comment: @sorrell -- see if you get voltage from live to neutral at the outlet with the fuse removed

Comment: Is the non-contact tester powered?  You may be looking at phantom voltage, which can be induced from nearby wires.  If plugging in a lamp makes this voltage *go away*, that's what you're dealing with. DVMs (common cheap digital readout voltmeters) are even worse for reporting phantom voltage, so they won't help.

Comment: I rest my case.

Answer (score 1):

A low impedance solenoid style or lamp style tester is the best tester for this type of troubleshooting.  If the circuit can't power a solenoid than you are dealing with an induced voltage.

Good luck!